# Not getting the response body for http post request in android?

Tags: android

Not getting the response body for http post request in android.
I am mentioning the userid, password in the name value pairs and putting in the httppost request by

```
postrequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

but on executing i am getting the response as SC_OK(200), but the response body is `null`.

One more problem is if i specify header in  HTTPGet or HTTPPost's request using `setHeader()` function i am getting BAD REQUEST (404) response.

Please help me in resolving the above issue.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: put the code where you call and read the response.

Comment: Did you verify that the server actually sent a response?

Comment: Server is not in our company, its third party server. And i am getting the BAD Request and from the header and the network logs i found that the reply is from server only

Comment: Even it's third party server, it would be a good idea to test the request works with something else besides your Android app. For example, do the same request with `wget` or `curl` and see if you get response body. If not, it's not a problem with Android, but with the remote server or with how you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

here's a method for easy POST to a page, and getting the response as a string. The first param (the HashMap) is a key-value list of parameters you want to send. There is no error handling so you'll have to do that:

```
public static String doPost(HashMap<String,String> params, String url) {
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            httpost.setURI(new URI(url));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpResponse response = null;

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();

        Set entryset = params.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = entryset.iterator();
        Log.d("Posted URL: ", url+" ");
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry mapentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            String key = ((String)mapentry.getKey()).toString();
            String value = (String)mapentry.getValue();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));

            Log.d("Posted param: ", key+" = "+value);
        }

        try {
            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
            try {
                httpost.setURI(new URI(url));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            response = getClient().execute(httpost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            return convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some connection error occurred, nothing we can do
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend pl try this way to get response from the Server..

Where Given link is the link where u want to post the request..

```
String link2 = "http://184.106.227.45/quaddeals/university-of-illinois/androids_deals/user_card_list.json";

DefaultHttpClient hc1 = new DefaultHttpClient();

ResponseHandler<String> res1 = new BasicResponseHandler();

HttpPost postMethod1 = new HttpPost(link2);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",account_userId));

postMethod1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs1));

String response1 = hc1.execute(postMethod1, res1);
```

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, Actually i using HttpClient and client.execute() and it is working fine in the Target but not in the simulator, as we are using the proxy in our company i tried putting proxy to the simulator with -http-proxy as well, but still no luck